# Using breadth first search: how do I get to the end vertex?

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

I am not sure why my code is not returning the correct path vertices. It is returning [a b c] instead of [a c f],and I don't know why.
Is there something I'm missing here or doing wrong in my algorithm?
Note: getNeighbors(String vertex) returns the connecting edges for the vertex in its parameter.

This is the test: My code stops at "assertEquals("c", route.next())" because it is returning "b" instead of a "c". my code' current output is [a b c] and the expected is [a c f]

```
public class PathingTest {

    @Test
    public void testPathing(){
        Graph cycle = new Graph("graphs/cycle.json");
        Iterator<String> route = cycle.getRoute("d", "b").iterator();
        assertEquals("d",route.next());
        assertEquals("b",route.next());
        assertFalse(route.hasNext());

        Graph tree = new Graph("graphs/tree.json");
        route = tree.getRoute("a", "f").iterator();
        assertEquals("a",route.next());
        assertEquals("c", route.next());
        assertEquals("f", route.next());
        assertFalse(route.hasNext());

        Graph disconnected = new Graph("graphs/disconnected.json");
        assertEquals(null, disconnected.getRoute("a", "f"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code here?

Comment: @raviiii1 Hi, here's my code. Thanks for looking at it!

Comment: Also, give the sample you are testing it on, and the expected output.

Comment: Didn't run your code but looks like you are collecting only the neighbors of the start vertex and that's it.  Am I correct assuming that a,b,c are the neighbors only? (and that "f" is a vertex beyond those immediate neighbors?

Comment: @raviiii1 I just added the test and the expected output.

Comment: @PamStums I see that now. But I'm not sure how to change it depending on the current vertex. I see that it probably is just giving the neighbors of "a". Do you have any suggestions on how to make sure that path only ends up with the vertices relevant to my route?

Comment: I'll try:  Every neighbor is a potential "true" path that will lead to the end vertex, but we don't know which... so we must pass all of them for every vertex. I think the "path" can not be a single object as we consider all paths, so we should have many "path" objects built recursively for every option.  Another approach is to use a Shortest-Path algorithm - can be found in JGraphT library.  Use Dijakstra (or Bellman-Form if you find an implementation).  That would give you not only the path from start to end, but will give you the **shortest** path from start to end.

Comment: Please post [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `queue` variable and the `visited` variable have different purposes, but in your case, they get updated in the same way, which is not correct.

Shortly, you add a node to the `queue` while processing its parent (which means that at some point in the future, that node is expecting to be processed too). Meanwhile, you only add a node to `visited` only after you have processed it (added its children to the queue).

Your `while` loop should look like this (please notice the position of the insertion into `visited`).

```
while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
    String current = queue.remove();
    path.add(current);

    visited.add(current);

    if (current == end) {
        return path;
    }

    Iterator<String> neighbors = getNeighbors(start).iterator();
    while (neighbors.hasNext()) {
        String n = neighbors.next();

        if (!visited.contains(n)) {
            queue.add(n);
        }
    }
}
```